# Django class based generic views and inheritance

Tags: django, django-views

So I'm writing this application and using the generic views objects ListView and ObjectView.

I've overridden the method get_context_data on both to be able to add the same extra context (no related to the object) on both cases.

Now I have two classes, one extending Listview and the other extending DetailView both with identical get_context_data methods.

While this is working fine is really hurting to see, is there a parent class that I can override the get_context_data from that will make the ListView and DetailView inherit the new get_context_data? It would look much nicer that way :)

Thank you.

X

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If how you are wanting to override the get_context_data are the same I would use a mixin.

```
class CommonMixinExample(object):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # do stuff in here
        return super(CommonMixinExample, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

class YourListView(CommonMixinExample, ListView):
    # other code

class YourDetailView(CommonMixinExample, DetailView):
    # other code
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand why the mixin should inherit from the object I'm trying to write a view for. What if I want to use the YourListView or YorDetailView classes to render other objects?

Comment: My mistake, I thought that with object you meant my example object not an actual python object, I get it now, I created the Mixin and it is working fine. Thank you!